# "error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘***’" error when calling a method from another class with iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, associative-array

I'm implementing a method which searches an object of type `Object` by its name within an associative array. Then displays its elements by using a method `display` which is defined within the class `Object`. The method is implemented this way:

```
//Method SearchObject in class Gestion
#include "object.h"
void Gestion::SearchObject(string nameobj) const{

    stringstream ss;

    auto it = objectname.find(nameobj);
    if (it == objectname.end())
        cout << "Not found!" << endl;
    else
           (*it)->display(ss); //Error reported in this line
           cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Nevertheless, when compiling I get the following error:

```
error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘const std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<Object> >’
            (*it)->display(ss);
```

The method `display` is declared within the class `Object` and I have already tested by calling it from other classes. In the header of class `Gestion` the variables are declared this way:

```
//File gestion.h
typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjPtr;
typedef map<string, ObjPtr> Objectmap;

class Gestion { 
private:
         Objectmap objectname;
public:
    Gestion(Objectmap objectname);
    virtual ~Gestion() {}

    virtual void SearchObject(string nameobj) const; 
};
```

How can I use the method `display` within this new method I'm implementing?

Comment: Using **both** `->`and `*` on the iterator tries to take you two levels down. One too many according to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators are modeled after pointers, so you can use the dereference operator `*` on them, or pointer-to-struct access operator `->` on them.

However, the pointer-to-struct access operator `->` is already doing the dereferencing so you can't combine both.

Either do `it->display(ss)`, *or* `(*it).display(ss)`.

---

Well that's a lie, since the iterator is "pointing" to a `std::pair`, whose `second` member is a pointer, so *that* you should dereference using `*` or `->`, like `it->second->display(ss)` or `(*it).second->display(ss)`, or `(*it->second).display(ss)` or `(*(*it).second).display(ss)`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Objmultomedia is std::pair. You need to call `display` from second element of pair:

```
it->second->display(ss);
```